# Работа с массивом

Tags: javascript

Дан массив объектов. Вывести массив телефонных номеров пользователей, имеющих баланс более 2000 долларов. И найти сумму всех балансов пользователей

```
    let users = [
{
"index": 0,
"isActive": true,
"balance": "$2,226.60",
"name": "Eugenia Sawyer",
"gender": "female",
"phone": "+1 (840) 583-3207",
"address": "949 John Street, Rose, Puerto Rico, 1857"
},
{
"index": 1,
"isActive": true,
"balance": "$2,613.77",
"name": "Pauline Gallegos",
"gender": "female",
"phone": "+1 (985) 593-3328",
"address": "328 Greenpoint Avenue, Torboy, North Dakota, 6857"
},
{
"index": 2,
"isActive": false,
"balance": "$3,976.41",
"name": "Middleton Chaney",
"gender": "male",
"phone": "+1 (995) 591-2478",
"address": "807 Fleet Walk, Brutus, Arkansas, 9783"
},
{
"index": 3,
"isActive": true,
"balance": "$1,934.58",
"name": "Burns Poole",
"gender": "male",
"phone": "+1 (885) 559-3422",
"address": "730 Seba Avenue, Osage, Alabama, 6290"
},
{
"index": 4,
"isActive": true,
"balance": "$3,261.65",
"name": "Mcfadden Horne",
"gender": "male",
"phone": "+1 (942) 565-3988",
"address": "120 Scholes Street, Kirk, Michigan, 1018"
},
{
"index": 5,
"isActive": false,
"balance": "$1,790.56",
"name": "Suzette Lewis",
"gender": "female",
"phone": "+1 (837) 586-3283",
"address": "314 Dunne Place, Bawcomville, Guam, 9053"
}
]
 let sum = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
      const user = users[index];
      if(user.balance >2000) {
        sum += parseFloat(user.balance.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
        console.log(user.phone + " $" + user.balance);
      }
    }

    console.log("сумма первышающая $2000 тысячи = " + "$" + sum);
```

Не понимаю как доделать.(выводит 0)

Comment: Дан массив, это хорошо, 2000 долларов еще лучше. А вопрос то в чем?

Comment: мне скопировать вопрос для вас ?

Comment: Скопируйте. В вашем вопросе нет ни одного знака вопрос "?". Вы просто констатировали факт, что вам надо найти. Ну как бы ок, ищите )

Comment: И зачем вы свое время потратили и мое, делать нечего?

Comment: А что вы делаете? Вы складываете номер пользователя и его счёт? Ну если вам просто нужно вывести пользователей, у которых баланс выше 2к долларов, то просто пройдитесь по массиву и запишите их данные, а потом уже выводить

Comment: `user.balance >2000` посмотрите сюда внимательно, и подумайте

Comment: Вы вот тут `if (user.balance > 2000)`  сравниваете число со строкой, поэтому `if` всегда возвращает `false`

Comment: так и как мне строку сделать числом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить вот таким способом:

```js
const users = [{
    "index": 0,
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,226.60",
    "name": "Eugenia Sawyer",
    "gender": "female",
    "phone": "+1 (840) 583-3207",
    "address": "949 John Street, Rose, Puerto Rico, 1857"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,613.77",
    "name": "Pauline Gallegos",
    "gender": "female",
    "phone": "+1 (985) 593-3328",
    "address": "328 Greenpoint Avenue, Torboy, North Dakota, 6857"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,976.41",
    "name": "Middleton Chaney",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "+1 (995) 591-2478",
    "address": "807 Fleet Walk, Brutus, Arkansas, 9783"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,934.58",
    "name": "Burns Poole",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "+1 (885) 559-3422",
    "address": "730 Seba Avenue, Osage, Alabama, 6290"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,261.65",
    "name": "Mcfadden Horne",
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "+1 (942) 565-3988",
    "address": "120 Scholes Street, Kirk, Michigan, 1018"
  },
  {
    "index": 5,
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,790.56",
    "name": "Suzette Lewis",
    "gender": "female",
    "phone": "+1 (837) 586-3283",
    "address": "314 Dunne Place, Bawcomville, Guam, 9053"
  }
]


function usersCheck(users) {
  let usersMax2000 = [];

  for (let user of users) {
    let tmp = +user["balance"].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    if (tmp > 2000) {
      usersMax2000.push(user);
    }
  }
  return usersMax2000;
}


function usersBalanceSumm(users) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let user of users) {
    let tmp = +user["balance"].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    sum += tmp * 100;
  }
  return sum / 100;
}


let usersResult = usersCheck(users);

console.log('Пользователи у которых баланс больше $2000');
for (user of usersResult) {
  console.log(user['name']);
}


console.log(`Общая сумма балансов пользователей у которых баланс больше $2000: ${usersBalanceSumm(usersResult)}`);

console.log(`Общая сумма балансов пользователей: ${usersBalanceSumm(users)}`);
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста для чего вы множите сумму на 100, потом возвращаете и делите сумму на 100 ? sum += tmp * 100;   return sum / 100;

Comment: Перевожу доллары в центы, что-бы избавится от числа с плавающей точкой.  Число с плавающей точкой в информатике не точное из за особенностей устройства компьютера. Потому в финансовых расчетах не пользуются числами с плавающей точкой. Попробуйте умножить один доллар и десять центов на один доллар и десять центов и проверить правильность результата.  `1.10 * 1.10 === 1.21;` по хорошему это делается вот так  `parseInt(1.10 * 100) * parseInt(1.10 * 100) / 100  / 100 === 1.21;`

Comment: спасибо большое за информацию, очень полезная