# Вывод свойств ключей

Tags: javascript

Подскажите  где допустил ошибку в коде. Должно вывести массив телефонных номеров пользователей, у которых баланс более 2000 долларов

```js
let users = [
    {
        "balance": "$2,226.60",
        "phone": "+1 (840) 583-3207",
    },
    {
        "balance": "$2,613.77",
        "phone": "+1 (985) 593-3328",
    },
    {
        "balance": "$3,976.41",
        "phone": "+1 (995) 591-2478"
    },
    {
        "balance": "$1,934.58",
        "phone": "+1 (885) 559-3422"
    },
    {
        "balance": "$3,261.65",
        "phone": "+1 (942) 565-3988"
    },
    {
        "balance": "$1,790.56",
        "phone": "+1 (837) 586-3283"
    }
]
function findBalance (array) {
    array.forEach(arrayItem => {
        for (let key in arrayItem) {
            if (arrayItem.balance.startsWith("$2") || arrayItem.balance.startsWith("$3")) {
                console.log(`${key}: ${arrayItem[key]}`);
                return arrayItem.phone;
            }
        }
    });
}
findBalance(users);
```

массив телефонных номеров пользователей, у которых баланс более 2000 долларов

Comment: `if (arrayItem.balance.startsWith("$2")) {` - вот тут ошибка

Comment: да и `for (let key in arrayItem)` тоже какая-то бессмыслица…

Comment: @Grundy этот пользователь задает этот же вопрос с разных аккаунтов уже 3ий раз. Вот [прототип](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479391/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc), остальные закрыты.

Comment: ну вот теперь решение доработайте. for внутренний не нужен. А чтоыб отфильтрвать баланс, надов зять строку, привести ее к числу каким-то образом, и потом сравнить с 2000.

Comment: @teran спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал таким образом, весь код расписал что к чему!

```js
function findRichBalance (array) {
    //Создаю переменную куда буду отправлять номера телефонов с балансом больше 2к$//
    let balanceMin2000 = [];
    //Создаю цикл для перебора массива//
    for (let key of array) {
        //Создаю переменную которая конвертирует строчное значение баланса в числовое
        const stringToNumber = +key["balance"].replaceAll(/[$,]/g, '');
        // Провожу сравнение переменной с числом 2000 (по заданию нужно сравнить с 2000)
        if (stringToNumber > 2000) {
            // Если данное значение прошло проверку добавляю номер телефона данного баланса в новый массив
            balanceMin2000.push(key["phone"]);
        }
    }
    //Возвращаю в консоль массив с номерами телефонов баланс которых больше 2к$//
    return console.log(balanceMin2000);
}
findRichBalance(users);
```